# How do I load / unload css changes quickly on a plone + Zope site ? (noob)

Tags: css, caching, plone, zope

Basically, i'm admin of a plone website and i want to try out changes in the plone.css, plus other stuff in the Base Properties and ploneCustom.css for my additionnal elements.

I want to be able to quickly swicth from my custom css to the default for trying out different versions of plone.css.

What's the best way ? Is it about the cache or should I try CSS Manager type switching ? If so how ?

When I "save" the contents of plone.css or other style properties, it either takes ages to show up or ages to disappear...

thanks.

Comment: Please try to ask one specific question and only one specific question, preferably with information about what you have done to find an answer before asking the question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(follows @aclark 's answer)....or in production mode, Css  are all merged in a single big css per performances reasons. There's a little trick to force the css refresh though: just go to Zope Management Interface -> portal_css. Here toggle the selection of any css (just to simulate a change in the configuration) and then at the end of the page click "Save". This makes Zope think that you made some change and it force it to refresh the css digest.

Comment: Actually you dont need to toggle anything! Just hitting "Save" should be enough to change the hash added to the production mode merged CSS and get the refresh.

Answer (score 7):

Enable portal_css debug mode e.g.:

[image: Enable portal_css debug mode]

Answer (score 1):

In the ZMI you can also go to the Statistics tab under ResourceRegistryCache and delete the CSS cache directly. Nice and quick. [image]

Answer (score 0):

What to do to work with CSS if you dont have access to ZMI (you are not admin of the site)?